# How to access the Schedule ID for each instalment of a LineItemSchedule

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I have Products that have schedules with just one revenue amount (and date) and there are some that have two installments.

When exporting this LineItemSchedule object, I can only see the second installment because the API that I'm working with can only see the last row inserted in a table. This becomes problematic when I try to import back a date because it will always write in the second installment date not the first.

Is there a trick (using apex or visualforce or a simple SOQL query perhaps) to always write the first Schedule ID in a custom field in the OpportunityLineItemSchedule object? I can then update the date in the first installment accordingly.

The first installment always has the first date so something like:

```
SELECT Id, MIN(ScheduleDate) FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [Order  by clause](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm)

```
SELECT Id ,ScheduleDate  FROM OpportunityLineItemSchedule where Opportunity=:yourOppId order by ScheduleDate
```

This will return all `OpportunityLineItemSchedule`  in incrementing order of schedule date.

You can add the LIMIT clause to get 1st row.